# Git push origin master ERROR following checklist on github.com new repo

Tags: git, repository, commit

This is my first time using git, and I am not sure what is going on, and I can't find an answer that is resolving the problem.

I am running:

```
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:OldWest/CakePHP-Tutorials.git
git push origin master
```

And everytime I run: push origin master, I get error: `Permission Denied (publickey). Fatal: The remote end hung unexpectedly.`

So I ran: `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate a local key. That did not resolve it.

Anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upload your public key to [your account](https://github.com/account) on GitHub so they know that it's you and not some random person. The key is located in the `.ssh` folder of your home directory.

See "Adding the key to your GitHub account" on [this page](http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup/).

Comment: Thanks that's what I was searching for!